# What is the ZF behavior for the imul instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, eflags

The instruction set reference says that the ZF is undefined for the imul instruction.  So what happens to the ZF if I multiply a value in a register by an immediate value of 0x0?

Comment: Related: [How is the sign flag calculated with the imul instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29901622) - SF is undefined as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefined means that result can be anything and none of the values matter anything.

Comment: So if the result of an imul operation is zero, the ZF could be 0?

Comment: @mkg190 it could be 0, 666 or 0xDEADBEEF.

Comment: @Andrey: ZF is only a single bit, it's always either zero or 1.  This is assembly language, not C undefined behaviour.  `setz al` will produce 0 or 1. You just don't know which.    `jz` will either go to the target or fall through, not jump somewhere else.  (And yes, on at least some CPUs, for example Skylake, it actually will set ZF=0 even when both halves of the result are zero.  Same if it's non-zero)